# python - gtk treeview - liststore with real-time update

Tags: python, pygtk

i am having a issue with treeview liststore trying to get a real-time update, and I created a example to simulate what I'd like to do.
I want liststore1 updated each loop.

http://img204.imageshack.us/i/capturadetela5.png/

it should update the treeview column 'speed' and give to it a different number every second,
something like a download manager.

```
import gtk
import gtk.glade
import random

builder = gtk.Builder()
builder.add_from_file('ttt.glade')
window = builder.get_object('window1')
treeview  = builder.get_object('treeview1')
store = builder.get_object('liststore1')
column_n = ['File','Size','Speed']
rendererText = gtk.CellRendererText()


for i in range(10):
    foo = random.randint(100,256)
    list_ =  [('arquivo1.tar.gz', '10MB', '%s k/s' % foo)]

for x,y in zip(column_n,range(3)):

    column = gtk.TreeViewColumn(x, rendererText, text=y)
    column.set_sort_column_id(0)    
    treeview.append_column(column)


for list_index in list_:
    store.append([list_index[0],list_index[1],list_index[2]])

window.show_all()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If that's your full code, you're missing the GTK main loop invocation.

You need to do two things (in this order)

1 - Connect your window's `destroy` signal to a function that calls `gtk.main_quit()`

```
def on_destroy(widget, user_data=None):
    # Exit the app
    gtk.main_quit()

window.connect('destroy', on_destroy)
```

2 - Start the GTK main loop:

```
gtk.main()
```

This is where your app is effectively launched, and it will appear to hang at this line until `gtk.main_quit()` is called.

More generally... you should clean up the code a bit there :) Look at the ["Hello World" demo](http://www.pygtk.org/pygtk2tutorial/examples/helloworld.py) from the [PyGTK tutorial](http://www.pygtk.org/pygtk2tutorial/index.html) - it basically covers those points and more in greater detail. You'll find that following their general structure for things helps immensely.

If you want timed updates, look at the functions [timeout_add](http://library.gnome.org/devel/pygobject/stable/glib-functions.html#function-glib--timeout-add) and [timeout_add_seconds](http://library.gnome.org/devel/pygobject/stable/glib-functions.html#function-glib--timeout-add-seconds) - depending on your version of PyGTK/PyGobject these will be in the `glib` or `gobject` modules.

(Incidentally, GTKBuilder XML files typically have the `.ui` extension, even though Glade doesn't know it.)

Comment: When I stumbled upon the timeout_add function in programming PyGTK I was one happy camper.

Comment: Don't forget to return `False` to make it stop (although not returning at all should work, since that implies `None`). The `idle_add` function is also really useful :)